# When loading module via #Requires -Module, unable to retrieve path or name of initiating script via $MyInvocation

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure a general way to get the name and path of a script on the import of a module.  There are three concerns that I have, and I have been unable to figure how to make the main one work.  Here is my 'test' code:

Test.ps1

```
#Requires -Version 5.0
#Requires -Module @{ModuleName='ModuleTest';RequiredVersion='1.0'}

#---remove module to retest the above line
# Remove-Module -Name ModuleTest -Force

#---uncomment and remove requires to test import
#Import-Module -Name ModuleTest -Force

write-host 'Done...'
```

ModuleTest.psm1 - Saved in module path, imported via $env:PSModulePath

```
#Requires -Version 5.0
write-host "callstack = $((Get-PSCallStack).Command -join '; ')"
write-host "ScriptName = $($MyInvocation.ScriptName)"
write-host "PSScriptRoot = $($MyInvocation.PSScriptRoot)"
write-host "PSCommandPath = $($MyInvocation.PSCommandPath)"
write-host "Location = $((Get-Location).path)"
function xyz{...}
function abc{...}
```

1) Import-Module from the command prompt, callstack returns **`<ScriptBlock`>**

```
callstack = ModuleGroup.psm1; <ScriptBlock>
ScriptName = 
PSScriptRoot = 
PSCommandPath = 
Location = D:\Powershell
Done...
```

2) Script using Import-Module returns full **MyInvocation** information

```
callstack = ModuleTest.psm1; Test.ps1
ScriptName = **D:\Powershell\psModules\ModuleTest\1.0\Tests\Test.ps1**
PSScriptRoot = D:\Powershell\psModules\ModuleTest\1.0\Tests
PSCommandPath = D:\Powershell\psModules\ModuleTest\1.0\Tests\Test.ps1
Location = D:\Powershell
Done...
```

3) Using #Requires -Module statement returns **no information** about caller.  (remove-module between tests)

```
callstack = ModuleTest.psm1
ScriptName = 
PSScriptRoot = 
PSCommandPath = 
Location = D:\Powershell
Done...
```

I have been searching and testing, trying scopes and $script/$global, and everything I could think of.  I would prefer the module code retrieve the values, versus the script passing them, so that I don't have to be mindful everytime I wish to reference the module.

If nothing else, I will not allow the #Requires and throw an error when MyInvocation has nothing in it.

Comment: I believe that this is an issue with [Module Auto-Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-6#module-auto-loading), and not `#Requires -Module`. Why not just manually load the module? `ipmo ModuleTest -Req '1.0'`

Comment: Yes, it is an issue with Module Auto Loading, I agree.  I would figure though, that the module that is auto-loaded would have the ability to 'see' what triggered it to load.  For now, I am going to use Import-Module and forgo the #requires -module.  In order to keep it clean, I'll code it to error out if the module is auto-loaded.  I was hoping there was a way though to get the name of the triggering script.

Answer (score 0):

The $MyInvocation variables are only set after scripts, functions, and scriptblocks are called. So the variable is not set when you use the command prompt. The Requires statement should not affect this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#myinvocation

Comment: I saw that MyInvocation is not returning results.  I was using it as an example and comparison to a direct calling import-module from within a script versus using the #Required -Module header. 

I am still trying to find a way to get that information, and am hoping I provided a good example to show that the information is probably there, and I just don't know how to get to it.

Comment: Rather than use the MyInvocation variable, does $PSscriptroot and $PSCommandPath get you the information you need?

Comment: Nope, both are null.